# Can't use words like "Can", "of" in full text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am using MsSQL server 2008, I am using CONTAINSTABLE with the search term "can", but the search query is not returning anything thought there are no stoplists attached to that catalog.

SELECT DISTINCT c.ID FROM City c
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(City, (Name), '"can"') AS city_tbl1 ON city_tbl1.[KEY] = c.ID

To make sure that this kinda exists I ran this query

update City SET Name = 'can' WHERE ID = 34

no results where returned.

Please help.

Thanks in advance
--Z

Comment: I've just deleted my answer stating that it may have to do with the minimum length of full text search as I'm now not too sure if this is the case in sql server. That's clearly what happens in MySQL, so maybe that's the hint.

Answer (score 4):

These words are so called "stopwords". They're ignored by the full text engine.

In mssql 2008 you can clear the stopwords-table by executing following code:

--Disable the stopwords-filter--

```
use yourDatabase;

create fulltext stoplist EmptyStopList;

alter fulltext index on yourFullTextTable
set stoplist EmptyStopList;
```

If the above commands do not work, make sure your database compatibility level is set to 100  (this means it's a 2008 database).

--Make sure--

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel youDatabase, 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your reply. I figured it out after you mentioned the confiuration, so thanks a lot.

But the issue was that can is in the system stopwords that somehow controls the index, so in the config I enabled transform noise words.

sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;

that just made it work.

Thank so much for your reply.
Cheers
--Z

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a textfile with common words that are ignored in the searches. If you want to add / remove words look in the directory Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTDATA\

Hope that helps.